Building a Controller on PHP
I have been building a website using PHP and I have ran into a problem when trying to build a controller. So I have my page url names listed as: "/", "/about", "/courses". The home page seems to be working but when I click on the about us page I am getting an error: "The requested URL was not found on this server." When I include .php for each of the URL page names, it works fine. Could someone help me out with this?
<a href="/" class= "<?php urlIs('/') ? 'bg-black text-black' : 'text-gray' ?> nav-link"> Home</a></li>

<li class="nav-item active"><a href="/about" class="<?php urlIs('/about.php') ?> nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                    
<li class="nav-item active"><a href="/courses" class="<?php urlIs('/courses.php') ?> nav-link">Courses</a></li>

When I include .php for each of the URL page names, it works just fine.

Are you using a framework not mentioned here?  Or otherwise in what way are your controllers different from just PHP pages?  What sort of routing logic do you have in place to direct requests to those controllers?

Controller is not a builtin concept in PHP and there're many ways to implement it. From your description, you just have individual PHP files in the public directory and you want to "beautify" URLs and hide the ".php" extension. To do that, you need to configure stuff in your web server. Which one is it? Apache? Nginx? IIS?

I am using Apache webserver with xampp

If your website doesn't have any routing logic, then you may be able to just add a some information in the web server's configuration that tells it to send addresses without an extention to php files.
If you are using Apache this would mean doing something like this in your .htaccess file:
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 [L]

Conversely, a lot of frameworks have rules like this in place that send all traffic to a single file, then that file reads the path and determines which php files need to get called from the path.
